# Integrating old spring mvc application with angular js application

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am pretty new with spring Mvc and new to angular js too. I have been working with integrating an old Spring mvc project which is connected to webapp folder with jsp's in it. What we are doing is creating a war file out of it and deploying it into a tomcat server.

Now I would like to move a new webapp folder with angular js views in it and remove the old jsp views completely. The way I am running it right now is.. start the tomcat server with deployed application and start the angular js as a separate server using grunt.

Could anyone help me with the steps as to how I can combine these two. Please let me know if any information is missing and you need to know further on this.

Thank you.

Comment: nelaturuk I do not get it. If I am not wrong, you deploy backend and fronend as two seperate packages. So angular js is not relevant with it. Is there a problem to load angular js in your jsp's?

Comment: Basically I want it to work like how jHipster application works, if you heard of jhipster. I want both back end and front end to be connected in the same war file. Is that not a possible thing? Should we load back end and front end as separate projects always ? with spring mvc and angular js ?